# How to create a randomly sized list of randomly generated numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell and I've been trying to figure out this problem for a while now.  I want to generate a list of a random size using randomRIO and have that list be populated with random numbers using randomIO.  I have tried to approach this problem by creating a function which takes in the randomly generated from randomRIO like so:

```
x <- randomRIO(1,5)
let y = randList x []
```

the function itself is something like this:

```
randList :: Int -> IO [Int] -> IO [Int]
randList 0 xs = return [xs]
randList g xs = do
            t <- randomIO
            let a = t:randList (g-1) xs 
            return [a]
```

I'm not sure how to handle the monad IO in a recursive function but this is how I'm thinking of it.  Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Note that it's strongly eschewed in Haskell to put something like this in `IO`. Better to accept an explicit `RandomGen` argument (or use a specialised monad which does just that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `replicateM` to repeatedly execute `randomIO`, generating a new number each time. You call `randomRIO` once up front to decide on the length of the list:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import System.Random (randomIO, randomRIO)

randList :: IO [Int]
randList = do
  len <- randomRIO (1,5)
  replicateM len randomIO
```

Now, your definition wasn't actually very far off. A couple of things though:

- Given that you expect to be able to call `randList x []`, the second argument of `randList` clearly is a plain list. Not an IO action of some sort. So your type should be

  ```
  randList :: Int -> [Int] -> IO [Int]
  ```
- In your first pattern match

  ```
  randList 0 xs = return [xs]
  ```

  Remember that `xs` is already a list. So when you do `return [xs]` you will get an `IO [[Int]]`, a list of lists. What you want here is a plain `return xs`.
- In your second definition

  ```
  randList g xs = do
      t <- randomIO
      let a = t:randList (g-1) xs 
      return [a]
  ```

  The expression `t:randList ...` makes no sense. The right-hand side of `:` must be a list. `randList` does not yield a list though, it yields an IO action. What you actually want to do is to treat the second argument of `randList` (the list) as an "accumulator", which is gradually built up. So you want to generate a number, add it to the accumulator, and then recurse with `g` decreased by one:

  ```
  randList g xs = do
      t <- randomIO
      randList (g-1) (t:xs)
  ```

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you so much!  Quick question.  Is there away to seperate the numbers with a ',' as in a normal list?  ***EDIT:  Disregard, I got a list of one several times by chance.  Thanks again!!